# cakephp 3.x how to check if mail send or not

Tags: email, cakephp, response, cakephp-3.0

i am sending mail using cakephp 3.0 this is my code

```
$email = new Email();
$siteEmail = "test@example.com";
$subject = "Message subject";
$email = new Email();
$email->from($siteEmail)
->to($userEmail)
->subject($subject);

$response = $email->send($message);
if($response) {
    $this->Flash->success(__('mail send'));
} else {
    $this->Flash->error(__('mail send fail'));
}
```

but how to check if mail is send or not if i print the $response variable than its print the array of all mail related data like to from message and subject no response like message is send or not how to check so that print the success or failure flash message when i use if else as shown above its always return true either mail sent or not

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Send failures are causing exceptions, `\Cake\Network\Exception\SocketException` to be exact, so wrap your `send()` call in [**a `try` block**](http://php.net/manual/language.exceptions.php), and evaluate possible catched exceptions.

```
use Cake\Network\Exception\SocketException;

// ...

try {
    $email->send($message);
    // success
} catch (SocketException $exception) {
    // failure
}
```

Comment: i have used this but did not solved my problem still always show success messaage

Comment: @DeepakGoyal Well then there probably is no error that (Cake)PHP would be able to notice.

Comment: @DeepakGoyal if this is not catching an error then the issue lies outside of your app so you won't be able to handle this sort of failure. As far as Cake will be concerned it has successfully done its bit.

Comment: can you please give me mail code because i have just add the mail code but its niether send mail nor show any error always show success please help me to resolve this